# docker extend base operating system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm learning to work with docker/docker-compose, and having a few issues now.

I can't really understand how it works, for example, if i run php7.2 image - what operating system is it running on ?

Currently i'm thinking about working on my new project with docker, but can't find a way to create docker configs.
What i want now is: Use base image/service with operating system - ubuntu, then i need extend that image/service and add services like java, mysql, also need to checkout 2 repositories which should be later run on that ubuntu service with java and mysql. How can i do that ? I've tried googling for some examples, but i'm not been able to find any good example.

I would really appreciate any help with that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As start example you can read http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/

You don't need to extend your image with other services because the paradigm here is "one container = one service". [Here best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/).